# Sort documents including fake one in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

I'm creating an application that will sort items in the DB in order to create a selective process.

This process, will consist of Users, and Registers in courses.

Each course, will have Users in it, and the SORT method to select them will vary depending on each course.

I'm implementing a way of 'simulating' the position of a user in a course, without matriculating it in the course, so that he can 'know' it's position prior to entering the selection process.

To do so, I imagined that I could use the same logic used after the user has already registered: Sort in the DB, return the list of ID's, and see what's the user index in that list.

However, I want just to `simulate`, without creating/updating anything. I cannot find a way to do that, without during the query, inserting a 'fake' document, but that cannot happen for reasons of security and integrity (inserting/removing items let the DB integrity broken during a short period of time, and can cause conflicts within logics of the application).

Doing the sorting on the DB, and re-doing it on the system is also not a good Idea as well, since there will be duplicated logic going on.

How can I 'fake' an document, without creating it during a query?

Comment: Why not actually create a document and just have a flag to determine whether it's real? You can then delete fake documents once they reach a certain age or when the user is finished "simulating."

Comment: I didn't want to touch the DB in order to simulate... Isn't there another way of doing it?